# Track to see when a view changes in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Does anyone know how to make angular fire an event when the view has changed? Or right when a view is requested and downloaded? I'm trying to add loading animations for when pages change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/OroP1DBE6AA/discussion) it looks like the `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors` are a good place to add this type of thing.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdam/dBR2r/) shows a good example on where to add code to start/stop a spinner for ajax requests. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dBR2r/8/) is similar but actually shows and hides a 'Loading...' div.

If you only want to show a spinner when views change you can limit your start/stop code to when `content-type` equals `text/html` similar to what [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/OroP1DBE6AA/YZ7BuhKI8eMJ) shows with `application/json`.

Note: in my tests it looks like the `headersGetter()['Content-Type']` in the `spinnerFunction` is omitted when retrieving my .html files whereas it is populated when making service calls.

Comment: Is this current for 1.2?

Answer (score 10):

I think a much simpler, adaptable approach would be to use the AngularJS `$http.pendingRequests.length` call. It returns the pending ajax call count. So when it reaches `0`, you're page is done loading.

You could create a directive that inserts a loading div (scrim) on any element and then waits for all ajax calls to resolve and then removes your spinner.

Here's the meat of the code to make your AngularJS directive:

```
        // Prepend the loading div to the dom element that this directive is applied.
        var scrim = $('<div id="loading"></div>');
        $(scrim).prependTo(domElement);

        /**
         * returns the number of active ajax requests (angular + jquery)
         * $.active returns the count of jQuery specific unresolved ajax calls. It becomes 0 if
         * there are no calls to be made or when calls become finished.
         * @return number of active requests.
         */
        function totalActiveAjaxRequests() {
            return ($http.pendingRequests.length + $.active);
        }

        /**
         * Check for completion of pending Ajax requests. When they're done,
         * remove the loading screen and show the page data.
         */
        scope.$watch(totalActiveAjaxRequests, function whenActiveAjaxRequestsChange() {
            if(totalActiveAjaxRequests() === 0){
                $log.log("done loading ajax requests");
                $(scrim).remove();
                $(domElement).css("position", "inherit");
            }
        });
```

Please note, $.active is undocumented.

Comment: Any time :) I just banged my head for a few hours on this and figured I'd share.

Comment: BTW you can also use `$scope.$watch` to achieve the same effect without the use of `setTimeout`. This would be a better choice since this goes along with the $scope digests. You can also use this plugin, but you would have to manually call `$scope.onReady()` when you're done. https://github.com/yearofmoo/AngularJS-Scope.onReady

Comment: Thanks again for $scope.$watch suggestion. Code updated for use in a directive (that's why scope isn't $scope).