# Angularjs Post-Receive Hook or Similar?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to call a function every time after a response is returned from a server without explicitly calling it after in the callback?

The main purpose is that I do have a generic error handler service that I call in every request's callback and I want to specify it somewhere and it shall be called automatically.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I gave Gloopy a +1 on solution, however, that [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787061/1207991) he references does DOM manipulation in the function defined in the config and the interceptor. Instead, I moved the logic for starting spinner into the top of the intercepter and I use a variable in the `$rootScope` to control the hide/show of the spinner. It seems to work pretty well and I believe is much more testable.

```html
<img ng-show="polling" src="images/ajax-loader.gif">
```

```js
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']).
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
    var spinnerFunction = function (data, headersGetter) {
        return data;
    };
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(spinnerFunction);
})
//register the interceptor as a service, intercepts ALL angular ajax http calls
.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q, $window, $rootScope) {
    return function (promise) {
        $rootScope.polling = true;
        return promise.then(function (response) {
            $rootScope.polling = false;
            return response;
        }, function (response) {
            $rootScope.polling = false;
            $rootScope.network_error = true;
            return $q.reject(response);
        });
    };
})
// other code left out
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is something I've been trying to do a while ago!

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution, but it didn't work for me. For some reason,  when the proper "then" handler is invoked, it has no reference to $rootScope anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never mind - this is a strange behavior. If I debug and evaluate "rootScope" I get "no reference" error. but if I simply use it, it works.. can't explain it.. thank you - used it. works well.

Comment: Actually, this solution is not working. The line $rootScope.polling = true; should be inside spinnerFunction as this is a beginning of request.

Comment: This code works fine for me, can you post a complete example showing how your change makes it work better?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean for requests using `$http` or a `$resource` you can add generic error handling to responses by adding code to the `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors`. See more in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787061/1207991).

Although it is about starting/stopping spinners using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdam/dBR2r/) you can add your code in the 'stop spinner' section with `// do something on error`. Thanks to zdam from [the groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/OroP1DBE6AA/R11P6dLFFowJ)!