# Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! with httpInterceptor (iFrame) IE

Tags: internet-explorer, http, request, angularjs, digest

I'm using AngularJS and I have a little question here. I just made my httpInterceptor service to display a spinner on a webpage when performing ajaxRequests but it is getting me this error when I run it within an iFrame using IE; it does not happen using Chrome, Firefox. Here is the code for the interceptor:

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope) {
        return function (promise) {
            $rootScope.$$childHead.spinner += 1;
            return promise.then(function (response) {
                $rootScope.$$childHead.spinner -= 1;
                return response;
            }, function (response) {
                $rootScope.$$childHead.spinner -= 1;
                return $q.reject(response);
            });
        };
    }).config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
        var spinnerFunction = function (data, headersGetter) {
            return data;
        };
        $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(spinnerFunction);
    });
```

For some reason it is displaying me this error when I run my appication inside an iFrame:

```
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:
```

I was wondering if this is caused because of running it within iFrame or if it is because of the promise object.

I've seen this error when using ng-repeat but I haven't found a reason of this. If you have had a similar problem please give me some advices. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are dipping into angular when referencing $rootScope.$$childHead. If this is an internal construct then this is most likely your problem. You seem to be racing with angular to update same field. [See this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863148/angularjs-post-receive-hook-or-similar/11870892#11870892)

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for you answer. About the $rootScope.$$childHead, I'm using it because it is the reference to the $scope I'm using in my controller. If I use $rootScope only it is not updating $scope.spinner from that controller.Do you know another option to access that scope?

Comment: Hi Omar, instead of accessing angular's innards, why not create a listener in your child scope (using $on) and use $broadcast from the rootscope to notify. Just an idea.