# Get $httpProvider from jquery so I can intercept messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an angular app with javascript code I can't touch (3rd party code).

I'd like to intercept the http messages from outside of angular. I have figured out how to get the controller and injector and can get the $http service, but I can't seem to get the `$httpProvider` so I can add an intercept something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956827/angularjs-intercept-all-http-json-responses)

Code I've got so far is (it's actually in a timeout but I left that out for brevity),

```
 $(window).load(
      ...
      var injector = angular.element('#myBody').injector();
      var httpProvider = injector.get('$httpProvider ');
      httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
         ...
```

but `httpProvider` isn't defined, `$http` is defined but it's not the same as the provider - I'm fairly new to angular, so is there any way to get the provider? Version is 1.1.5

Comment: Is your script loaded synchronously on the page?

Comment: yes. It's loaded after the angular and 3rd party scripts.

Comment: Perhaps you can extend the app.
`angular.module("3rdPartyApp").config(function($httpProvider){...});`

Comment: Too easy - it works a treat - thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the question - as [calebboyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592994/calebboyd) said:

Perhaps you can extend the app.

```
angular.module("3rdPartyApp").config(function($httpProvider){...});
```

This works.