# Typed.js jQuery plug-in not working with ngRoute

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins, ngroute

I'm building a simple website with AngularJS to learn more about the framework. I want to include a typing animation on the home view, and after looking through several options, I decided to add the jQuery plug-in Typed.js.

I began by adding all of the code in my index.html to see if I properly added it, which worked. But when I moved the script and HTML element into separate files and set up the route in app.js, the animation not longer played.

I tried following the solution laid out here in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669827/how-can-i-trigger-an-event-when-an-angular-js-route-template-has-been-loaded), but wasn't able to get it to work for me.

I've been looking into the possibility of creating a custom directive after reading some other articles, as well as tinkering with several jQuery event listeners, but I'm fairly stumped at this point.

I've researched some options that I can use if this one doesn't pan out, but I'd really like to stick with it to see if I can't walk away with a deeper understanding of Angular.

Comment: You have to show us some code. How are you trying to use it?

Answer (score 4):

I have had a go at making [typed.js](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/) into an angular directive. See the [Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Hbbj5u11Las6cG8VsXs).
The html directive is:

```
<typedjs strings=texttyping></typedjs>
```

where `texttyping` is an array defined in the scope. The javascript is:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.texttyping = ["Hello, this is the first sentence", 
                        "Second sentence",
                        "Final sentence" ]
}])
.directive('typedjs', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',    
        scope: { strings: '=' },
        template:'<span id="typed-output"></span>',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
          var options = {strings: $scope.strings,
                          typeSpeed: 2,
                          contentType: "html",
                          showCursor:true,
                          cursorChar:"="
                          };

          $(function(){
            $("#typed-output").typed( options );
          });
        }
    };
});
```

It would be good to put the options into the directive, rather than in an array in the js.

Answer (score 0):

```
controller.js
myApp.controller('updateController',['$scope',function($scope){
$scope.updates = ['This is update 1',
'This is the second update!'];

//typed.js function

$(function(){
    $(".update-box p").typed({
      strings:$scope.updates,
      typeSpeed: 40,
      loop: true,
      backDelay: 1500,
      contentType: 'text',
      loopCount: false,
      cursorChar: " |"
    });
  });
}]);

In the html page:
<div class="update-box" ng-controller="updateController">
        <p></p>        
</div>
```