# Loading data ajax style

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I jsut started learning angular.js. Can you guys show me the right way to make a page that initially presents an ajax loader element saying 'Loading data' or something like that. Then after data's been fetched it would update the view and hide the element. I can put stuff in page load event using jquery, but how do you do that using pure angular? So far I figured out how to put that in click event:

```
<div ng-app="VideoStatus" ng-controller="VideoStatusCtrl">
    <button ng-click="getVideos()">get videos</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('VideoStatus', ['ngResource']).run(function(){ 
       // I guess somehow I can start fetching data from the server here, 
      //  but I don't know how to call Controller methods passing the right scope 
    });

    function VideoStatusCtrl($scope, $resource) {
        $scope.videoStatus = $resource('/Videos/GetStatuses', { callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK' });

        $scope.getVideos = function () {
            $scope.videoResult = $scope.videoStatus.get();
            console.log('videos fetched');
        };
    };
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786764/track-to-see-when-a-view-changes-in-angularjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kudos to  [Adam Webber & Peter Bacon Darwin](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/angular/show%2420directive%2420from%2420service/angular/BbZ7lQgd1GI/WuwI--o7nlIJ)

Here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/88wTp8?p=preview)

**Here is my version [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z8H8pO?p=preview)** that make loading as a directive with modal popup feature

Here is the tutorial to use my version

you only need loading.js and modal.js and reference jQuery and twitterbootstrap css.

in your code,

Only 2 steps you need to do with your code.

1. Add the following code to HTML

   < div data-loading> < /div>
2. Add **LoadingModule** module to your application module.

   angular.module('YourApp', ['LoadingModule'])

Comment: too bad this is the only working solution I have found so far.

Comment: Ok, I try to make it as simple as possible. You only need to do 2 steps

Comment: sorry I still feel myself kinda lost here... can you show me a simple example where I have some text when the page loads, and then on the callback of resource's get method it hides..

Comment: Do you check the 2nd example ? You pretty much don't need to do anything if you use my version. only 2 thing. 1. Add a tag 2 Add module name LoadingModule

Comment: I'm too new to angular to get all that $scope and $watch stuff. Maybe soon I can get that all, but right now I need to understand simply how to have some text on the page load and then how to hide it on successful get

Comment: modified your code like: angular.module('VideoStatus', ['ngResource','LoadingModule']) , and add < div data-loading> < /div> to your html. And link loading.js and modal.js from my example . You are done. You don't need to know $watch or anything

Comment: How about this, post your working code to plunker and I will fix it for you

Comment: here, can you please show me on this example? http://plnkr.co/edit/8lQERI?p=preview I'd appreciate that indefinitely

Comment: thank you man... you're offering me a ready-made solution. I'm gonna use that for now, but I'm gonna need to take some time and learn about $httpProvider and interceptors. I didn't expect that answer to my question would be a lil bit complicated, given the fact how angular makes everything else so simple

Comment: btw... you didn't tell me how to start loading the data right away on the pageload... not on button click :)

Comment: It is right away on the pageload if there is any post get etc.

Comment: no I mean it gets data from twitter only on button click... how can I force it onPageload instead?

Comment: Oh I got it! I got it!.. I gotta use `ng-init`! Yay!