# a way to know when Angular $http is "requesting"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I make an `$http` request when a user clicks a `<button>` and I disable/hide/show several elements on screen until the request comes back with either `success` or `error`

Is there a way to know that `$http` hasn't had a response yet? The way I am doing it right now is I have a var in my controller called `$scope.requesting` which I then use in my HTML page like so:

```
<img src="img/loader.gif" ng-show="requesting" />
```

so basically when `$scope.requesting` is true, show the spinning ajaxyish loader.

I'd like to ditch the `$scope.requesting` if possible and use whatever `$http` has to offer, if any at all.

**Login Controller**

```
function LoginForm($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.requesting = false;

    $scope.login = function()
    {
        $scope.requesting = true;

        $http.post('resources/request.php', data, {timeout:20000})
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
            {
                $scope.requesting = false;
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
            {
                $scope.requesting = false;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I do the same thing but toggle the requesting off on complete vs success or error. Can't think of a better way at the moment.

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/dBR2r/8/) seems like what you are looking for. I'm too lazy to test it out and turn it into a proper answer. Maybe you can post the end result as an answer.

Comment: @TrevorSenior ok good to know, I'm not the only one doing it that way. Dmitry's answer seems promising. drozzy, the behavior is certainly there, just a tad more complicated than my current solution

Comment: @Ronnie When you asking about "whatever `$http` has to offer" - you are talking exactly about `$httpProvider`. I too think it's complicated, but i'm afraid you gotta bite the bullet.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can make use of `$http.pendingRequests` array of config objects for currently pending requests. It is possible to use it that way:

```
$scope.isLoading = function () {
   return $http.pendingRequests.length !== 0;
};
```

Comment: That seems like it would work, except according to http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#pendingRequests `pendingRequests` is "primarily meant to be used for debugging purposes" which is kind of discouraging. I wonder why

Comment: Yep, I agree with you, this remark takes my sleep too.
Btw just stepped on this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786764/track-to-see-when-a-view-changes-in-angularjs answer to it contains all the needed links(especially this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/OroP1DBE6AA/dG4X3M_XvuAJ )

Comment: Sorry for being a noob. I heard from my friend that when you use a websocket in your app, then you look at network, it shows a continuous/open request/(or something). I wonder if this solution will detect that websocket connection as a pending request or not.

Comment: Hi @boi_echos. Websockets are not using http and hence won't be shown as pending request.

Comment: How to check pending request for $resource service? I know $resource internally uses $http but that does not work in my case. I am trying to create directive in typescript which check for pending request.
Check this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226567/create-directive-in-typescript-to-show-loading-progress-in-angular

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers here really nailed it for me, and I shun using `$http.pendingRequests`, so here's what I've done

My use case was that I had to show a simple "Loading.." message on the top of my viewport if I had any in-flight requests doing things on the server.

Inside `.config`, I've registered a new Interceptor. and inside there I've added a simple counter that increments by 1 per request and decrements per response.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push([function () {
    var pendingRequestsCounter = 0;
    return {
        request: function (request) {
            pendingRequestsCounter++;
            if (pendingRequestsCounter > 0) {
                // we have some pending requests, so do something here 
            }
            return request;
        },
        response: function (response) {
            pendingRequestsCounter--;
            if (pendingRequestsCounter === 0) {
                // we have no pending requests, so do something else here 
            }
            return response;
       }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

this [jsbin project](http://jsbin.com/nileriweqo/edit?html,js,console,output) takes @DmitryEvseev's answer to the next step. It provides finer control over which requests can be used to trigger "loading...".

Those requests with `{ showLoader: true }` are used to show the 'loading...' panel.

HTML

```
  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="spinnerController as vm">
      <div ng-if="vm.isLoading()">Loading ...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .config(config)
  .factory('httpLoader', httpLoader)
  .factory('httpLoaderInterceptor', httpLoaderInterceptor)
  .controller('spinnerController', spinnerController);

function config($httpProvider) {
  //adding the default http status code handler
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpLoaderInterceptor');
}

function httpLoader() {
  var pendingReqs = {};
  var factory = {
    addPendingReq: addPendingReq,
    subtractPendingReq: subtractPendingReq,
    getPendingReqs: getPendingReqs
  };
  return factory;

  function addPendingReq(url) {
    console.log('adding url', url);
    pendingReqs[url] = true;
  }

  function subtractPendingReq(url) {

    console.log('removing url', url);
    delete pendingReqs[url];
  }

  function getPendingReqs() {
    return sizeOf(pendingReqs);
  }
}

function httpLoaderInterceptor($q, httpLoader) {

  var factory = {
    request: request,
    response: response,
    responseError: responseError
  };

  return factory;

  function request(config) {
    console.log('request', config.url);
    if (config.showLoader) {
      httpLoader.addPendingReq(config.url);
    }
    return config;
  }

  function response(res) {
    console.log('response', res.config.url);
    if (res.config.showLoader) {
      httpLoader.subtractPendingReq(res.config.url);
    }
  }

  function responseError(res) {
    console.log('responseError', res.config.url);
    if (res.config.showLoader) {
      httpLoader.subtractPendingReq(res.config.url);
    }
    return $q.reject(res);
  }
}

function spinnerController($http, httpLoader) {
  var self = this;
  self.isLoading = function() {
    return httpLoader.getPendingReqs() > 0;
  };

  $http.get('http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34561385',{
    showLoader: true
  });
  $http.get('http://www.amazon.com', {
    showLoader: true
  });
  $http.get('http://www.yahoo.com',{
    showLoader: true
  });
  $http.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com',{
    showLoader: true
  });
}

function sizeOf(obj) {
  var size = 0,
    key;
  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      size++;
    }
  }
  return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this directive:
https://github.com/afeiship/angular-isloading

### css:

```
body {
  font-family: 'STHeiti', 'Microsoft YaHei', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

.loading-widget {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.loading-widget,
.loading-widget[data-visible] {
  display: none;
}

.loading-widget[data-visible=true] {
  display: block;
}

.loading-widget img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

### html:

```
<div class="loading-widget"
     isloading
     loading="loading"
     data-visible="{{loading}}"
>
  <img src="svg/default.svg" alt="">
</div>
```

### javascript:

```
  angular.module('TestApp', ['nx.widget']);

  angular.module('TestApp').
  controller('MainCtrl', function ($http, $q, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.loading = false;
    var s1 = $http.get('http://www.baidu.com');
    var s2 = $http.get('http://www.sina.com');
    var s3 = $http.get('http://www.163.com');
    var s4 = $http.get('http://www.qq.com');
    var s5 = $http.get('http://www.hao123.com');

    //you need a VPN if you're a Chinese(Thanks to the GFW)
    var s6 = $http.get('https://www.google.com/');


    $q.all([s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6]).then(function (responses) {
      console.log(responses);
    })


  });
```

### description:

- isloading `<!--1.attach the directive-->`
- loading="loading" `<!--2.write the scope.loading to the app.$rootScope-->`
- data-visible="{{loading}}" `<!--2.read loading props for CSS-->`