# Create directive in typescript to show loading progress in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, progress-bar

I am trying to create directive in Typescript which will keep watch on pending $resource requests. I want only one directive as an attribute which will be used with div in index.html to show loading progress. Below is my code for directive.

```
module app.common.directives {

interface IProgressbarScope extends ng.IScope {
    value: number;
    isLoading: any;
    showEl: any;
}

class Progressbar implements ng.IDirective {

    static $inject = ['$http'];
    static instance(): ng.IDirective {
        return new Progressbar;
    }
    //transclude = true;
    restrict = 'A';
    replace = true;

    link = function (scope: IProgressbarScope, elements: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, $http: ng.IHttpService) {

        debugger;
        scope.isLoading = function () {
            return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
        };
        scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (v) {
            debugger
           if (v) {
                elements.addClass("hidediv")
            } else {
                elements.removeClass("hidediv");
            }
        });
    }
}

angular.module('app')
    .directive('progressbar', Progressbar.instance);
}
```

in Index.html, it is used as below:

```
 <div progressbar id="myProcess" name="myProcess">
     // loading image
 </div>
```

But in directive, $http is always undefined. Note that I am not using $http directly. I a using $resource service for making server side api requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `$http` undefined is, you are trying to get `$http` dependency from `link` function of directive. Basically 4th parameter of link function stands for `require` controller.

You should Ideally get that injected dependency instance from `Progressbar` constructor function.

```
class Progressbar implements ng.IDirective {
    _http: ng.IHttpService; //defined _http variable
    static $inject = ['$http'];
    //asking for dependency here
    static instance($http: ng.IHttpService): ng.IDirective {
        this._http = $http; //get `$http` object assigned to `_http`
        return new Progressbar;
    }
    //transclude = true;
    restrict = 'A';
    replace = true;

    //removed dependency from here
    link = function (scope: IProgressbarScope, elements: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) { 

        //use arrow function here
        scope.isLoading = ()=> {
            return this._http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
        };
        //use arrow function here
        scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, (v)=> {
           if (v) {
                elements.addClass("hidediv")
            } else {
                elements.removeClass("hidediv");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can't I use elements.show() property instead of adding class? I am getting "angular.js:13550 TypeError: elements.show is not a function" error if I use elements.show()

Comment: @MicrosoftDeveloper check updated answer, you should use `Arrow function` instead of plain javascript function

Answer (score 0):

define $scope.isLoading inside directiveController and make $http call from service layer.

basic controller.ts

```
export class sampleController {

    // inject service here  
    constructor() {

    }

    public isLoading() {
        callServiceFunction();
    }
}

sampleController.$inject['service'];
```

Import this controller inside custom directive.

SampleService.ts

```
export class sampleService {
  constructor() {


  }

}
sampleService.$inject = ['$http'];
```

Register this service inside app module.

For more info refer [sample Importing and exporting example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263357/how-to-declare-and-import-typescript-interfaces-in-a-separate-file/37274572#37274572)  and [large scale app architecture](https://github.com/comsysto/angular-architecture)