# document.ready alternative for AngularJS outside of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a little Chrome extension to interact with Angular website. I can catch full page reload successfully via `$(document).ready()`, but page changes via `ng-view` don't change `ready` state, so I'm not sure how to catch that event from within a Chrome extension.

How should I go about catching `ng-view` changes from Chrome extension? Preferably without introducing extension dependency to AngularJS.

Comment: Have you tried listening for the popstate event?

Comment: @dewd No, I'll have to try. I am afraid of the issue with popstate changing before the DOM is rendered though.

Comment: Thats a possibilty.  Haven't used angular for about 18 months so don't recall even if pushstate is used - it might not be as its not pre IE10. I'm sure someone who knows more about the view/ state relationship will be able to help.

Comment: @dewd, Tried the popstate, doesn't look like it's working. I think URL changes before there's DOM to manipulate.

Comment: ..which makes sense. popstate does get triggered though? in any case, looks like elzi's more on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM ready equivalent for angular is

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('Hello World');
});
```

If you want to detect a view change, you can look at `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors`. Check out the first answer [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786764/track-to-see-when-a-view-changes-in-angularjs)

**EDIT** I see now you mean detecting angular events from outside of angular? I'll leave my answer here - though it is likely not an exact answer to your question.